# How to create vector drawable for Twitter?

Tags: android, drawable, vector-graphics

I like the Vector Drawable assets that can be used with the latest version of gradle (1.5.0).

How would a newbie go about creating a vector drawable for the Twitter bird? https://about.twitter.com/company/brand-assets

Comment: I assume you should take adobe illustrator and draw vector image

Comment: did you find/create one? Do not have illustrator nor windows nor the needed skillset for this task ..

Answer (score 5):

Personally, having an example asset (like on the brand-asset page) I use Inkscape. Most common steps are:

1. Import an example asset to the Inkscape (on a separate layer),
2. Create a path on top of the image placed on the layer behind,
3. Save work as a *.svg file,
4. Convert *.svg to vector drawable (using Android Studio or any tool that can be easily found in the network).

On the other hand, I really like to play with [path data](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathData) by hand. It is worth to create and maintain a git repository with created icons.

Example icon:

[image]

Vector drawable source:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="24dp">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00aced"
        android:pathData="M22.46,6C21.69,6.35 20.86,6.58 20,6.69C20.88,6.16 21.56,5.32 21.88,4.31C21.05,4.81 20.13,5.16 19.16,5.36C18.37,4.5 17.26,4 16,4C13.65,4 11.73,5.92 11.73,8.29C11.73,8.63 11.77,8.96 11.84,9.27C8.28,9.09 5.11,7.38 3,4.79C2.63,5.42 2.42,6.16 2.42,6.94C2.42,8.43 3.17,9.75 4.33,10.5C3.62,10.5 2.96,10.3 2.38,10C2.38,10 2.38,10 2.38,10.03C2.38,12.11 3.86,13.85 5.82,14.24C5.46,14.34 5.08,14.39 4.69,14.39C4.42,14.39 4.15,14.36 3.89,14.31C4.43,16 6,17.26 7.89,17.29C6.43,18.45 4.58,19.13 2.56,19.13C2.22,19.13 1.88,19.11 1.54,19.07C3.44,20.29 5.7,21 8.12,21C16,21 20.33,14.46 20.33,8.79C20.33,8.6 20.33,8.42 20.32,8.23C21.16,7.63 21.88,6.87 22.46,6Z"/>
</vector>
```